# Replace Rectangle on Canvas with Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I'm building a simple video game using HTML Canvas and JavaScript. I'm trying to replace a black square with an image of a strawberry, but the image is not displaying on the canvas. How would I make the image replace the square?

```
this.draw = function() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "strawberry.png";
  ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 10, 10);   
}
```

Comment: The variable is "image" but you are trying to draw "img"

Comment: Thank you. I corrected the variable, but the code is still not working. The error is "drawImage is not a function."

Comment: I can't see the top of your code, but there needs to be something that defines the ctx variable.  Something like: var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");  After that, ctx should allow the drawImage function

Comment: @ATD Thank you again, the image is not showing up yet but I am no longer seeing the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the image may not have loaded by the time the code is being called.  You will need to wait for that to happen.

Try:

```
function loadimage() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas"); 
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d"); 
  var img = new Image();
  img.src = "strawberry.png";
  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  }
}

window.onload = loadimage;
```

I have put a version of this code (I have a different image filename for my test) into a SCRIPT tag in the HEAD section of the page.  The code runs when the page has finished loading, but the code itself waits for the img.onload event to be triggered before actually drawing the image.  And, change "myCanvas" to the ID of your canvass tag.

Comment: This solved my problem, the image is now displaying on the canvas. Thank you!

Comment: np.  I purposely left out the bit about the rectangle and I wasn't sure what this requirement was.  I hope that you can now add this back in to the code to get what you need?

Comment: The rectangle was a temporary placeholder so I could see where the image was supposed to display and it was not needed for the project. Your answer fixed the problem perfectly! Thank you again!

Comment: ah, ok.  I generally do something similar by putting different coloured border's on HTML elements - I guess that's the same sort of thing!